# Laravel 4 routing with params issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So what I am trying to do is create a link the displays the user profile. The link I desire is localhost/user/{username} but the link I get with with the code I currently have is localhost/user?{username}. 
Here is my route code:

```
/* Profile Link */
Route::get('user/{username}', array(
'as' => 'profile-user-link'
));
```

I am not using a controller. Here is my view code:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile-user-link', Auth::user()->username) }}">My Profile</a></li>
```

Can someone explain why I am not getting my desired link output. Thank you

Comment: Would you check with laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) ?

Comment: Yes I have but it says this [2014-11-26 05:25:14] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mom\a\bootstrap\compiled.php:5329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Route::get(
    'user/{username}',
    array(
        'as' => 'profile-user-link',
        'uses' => 'userController@profile' // <-- You didn't use any handler
    )
);
```

**UserController:**

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function profile($username)
    {
        // Make sure User model and username field exists
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        // Do something with $user
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may also use something like this (Not Good Practice):

```
Route::get('user/{username}', function($username) {
    // Make sure User model and username field exists
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    // Do something with $user
});
```